# How do I Sum Columns in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datatables

Here is my Table, how do I sum the price and qty fields at the bottom of the table?

```
def output_action_header(text)
      puts "\n#{text.upcase.center(60)}\n\n"
    end

    def output_stock_table(stock=[])
    print " " + "Stock Type".ljust(30)
    print " " + "Number".ljust(20)
    print " " + "Transaction".ljust(20)
    print " " + "Price".rjust(6) + "\n"
    puts "-" * 90
    stock.each do |rest|
      line =  " " << rest.name.titleize.ljust(30)
      line << " " + rest.qty.titleize.ljust(20)
      line << " " + rest.transaction.titleize.ljust(20)
      line << " " + rest.formatted_price.rjust(6)
      puts line
    end
    puts "-" * 90
  end
```

Comment: what does stock look like going into the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby on Rails and e.g. `qty` is a number, you can do:

```
stock.sum(&:qty)
```

or if you are using Rails, but `qty` is not a number:

```
stock.sum { |rest| rest.qty.to_i }
```

If you're not using Rails, you can do:

```
stock.inject(0) { |sum, rest| sum + rest.qty }
```